# ScriptInjector to inject script on spcific div

Tags: javascript, gwt

What is the approach to inject a script with `ScriptInjector` to inject to a specific div, e.g:

I want to inject a script with `src='http://ads.qadservice.com/t?id=123'` inside a specific div (e.g. to `top-ads-large`). The reason is for the ability to inject the on the bottom of GWT EntryPoint `onModuleLoad()` such that it won't be blocking the GWT app loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="top-ads-placeholder" class="uk-hidden-small uk-hidden">
            <div id="top-ads-small" class="uk-hidden-small">
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.qadservice.com/t?id=123'></script>
            </div>
            <div id="top-ads-large" class="uk-hidden-medium uk-hidden-large uk-container-center uk-width-1-1">
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.qadservice.com/t?id=123'></script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScriptInjector` class is designed to attach to the head of the given `window` object (typically the top window is selected, but you can configure this). This is not configurable, since customizing it wouldn't achieve anything meaningful.

> such that it won't be blocking the GWT app loading.

This doesn't make any sense. The app has *already* loaded, so its loading cannot be blocked by a script that it selects to load. If the GWT app *hadn't* loaded, you couldn't use the `ScriptInjector` or any other java/js classes yet.

If your ad script *assumes* that the page hasn't finished loading (probably because it wants to do a `document.write`), then ScriptInjector is way too late to run it - anything in `onModuleLoad` or later is well after the document has been downloaded and all JS run. In that case, you must actually make this script be in the html page itself (where, ironically, it would block the GWT app from running...).